# Cpp header file missing variable names

Tags: c++

So I was looking at a String header file with the following declaration:

```
string(const char*);
```

How can I use the input parameter if there is no variable name for it? Also, is there any point in not writing the variable name. I feel like you would be screwed if you had a method that takes into 2 parameters of the same type. But the main question is how can I even access this input parameter without a variable name. Thanks!

Comment: That's probably the prototype. The constructor is most likely defined elsewhere with a named parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as the compiler is concerned, it doesn't need to know the actual name of the parameter when the function is being declared.  All it needs is the signature of the function: the return type, name, and the parameter types.

You only need the parameter name when you *define* the function, i.e. in a source file.

```
// foo.h
void foo(const char*);

// foo.c
#include "foo.h"
void foo(const char * c) {
    //OK
}

void bar(const char*) {
    //Indeed, we have no way to access the parameter
}
```

As long as these signatures match, everything will work fine.  If this is your header file though, it's usually better to include the parameter name in the declaration as it is useful documentation.

Comment: Incidentally, if you don't actually need the parameter (but you have to use a particular function signature, e.g. for a callback or a virtual function) you can omit its name even in the function definition. This has the advantage of silencing compiler warnings about unused parameters.